# How to compile scss file in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-shortcode

I have on of the website that are the blogging site build in wordpress. And in this website using scss and if i have change this scss file and save than changes not made. If anyone know that how i compile our scss file in wordpress than please let us know
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below tutorials will guide  you on how to set up SCSS

- https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-use-sass-with-wordpress-a-step-by-step-guide
- https://beautifytools.com/css-to-scss-converter.php
- https://jsonformatter.org/css-to-scss

if you have no idea about the command line then simply install the plugin

- https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-scss/